# Raise bounty questions one level up

Tags: feature-request, bounties

For example, like following.

[alt text http://img205.imageshack.us/img205/720/bounties.png](http://img205.imageshack.us/img205/720/bounties.png)

And, also adding special sort tabs would be great.

Comment: I think that would detract from the 99.99% of the questions that don't offer bounties.

Answer (score 3):

I think the "featured" tab on the homepage is sufficient.